# New to postgres sql -- slow deletes ever after taking out the fkey contraints, no triggers and fresh reindex

Tags: postgresql, sql-delete

[image]Alright, so I have a table that is extremely slow on delete even after removing fkey constraints and extra indexes aside from the one created for id; and finally reindexing the table after. When I delete with the explain plan it doesn't show anything interesting and the rows are around 7k, what else is there to check? A another table within the same database deletes in 3min for 184k rows.There are also no triggers associated with the table. Doesn't reindexing after dropping Fkeys also decouple for any referencing tables? This is the only thing I can think of. I also checked for bloated tables and that also seems to be just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the query you are using and the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you prevent the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: Bah, new to this database and finally the analyze came back there are missing fkey index all over. Once added this was no longer an issue finished in a couple secs as expected.